# React Native: Expo Command not Found

Tags: react-native

I am completely new to react native and trying to set up my environment. When I type in "expo init projectname" I get "-bash: expo: command not found."

I assume I am on the wrong path based on similar posts, but the instructions I have seen previously have not worked for me.

For reference, when I type in "$PATH" I get the line below.
"-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands: No such file or directory"

What do I need to do to create a React Native Project?

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I found out "sudo expo init" works as I am on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) to setting up your development environment with React Native and Expo.

Also make sure you have node installed (from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)) as you have to use npm to install the packages. You can check if node and npm are installed by running `node -v` and `npm -v` from terminal.